# Blazor application is getting Forbidden (403) when calling an external API (which works fine in PostMan)

Tags: outlook-restapi, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

Visual Studio 2019, .NET 3.0 preview, Created a blazor application. Trying to get weather data from https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/ALY/59,14/forecast.
I am using HttpClient in C#. This is getting forbidden (403) response

Tried to add CORS policty

```
private async Task<IWeatherDotGovForecast> RetrieveForecast()
        {
            string url = @"https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/ALY/59,14/forecast";
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (response != null)
            {
                var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherDotGovForecast>(jsonString);
            }

            //return await _httpClient.GetJsonAsync<WeatherDotGovForecast>
            //  ("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/ALY/59,14/forecast");

            return null;
        }
```

I expected JSON data from  https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/ALY/59,14/forecast

Instead, I am getting Forbidden (403) status code

Comment: 403 mean the request is [Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403). Do you need to specify an API key in your request? The server is probably expecting a certain set of headers that are not being passed with the JS call.

Comment: Right after posting this question, I tired the following and it worked.             ProductHeaderValue header = new ProductHeaderValue("MyPlayGroundLibrary", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
            ProductInfoHeaderValue userAgent = new ProductInfoHeaderValue(header);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(userAgent);

Comment: @shanthu - you can post that as a self-answer. The comment isn't readable.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not related to Blazor but weather.gov requires a User-Agent header in any HTTP request.

Applications accessing resources on weather.gov now need to provide a User-Agent header in any HTTP request. Requests without a user agent are automatically blocked. We have implemented this usage policy due to a small number of clients utilizing resources far in excess of what most would consider reasonable.

Use something like this:

```
 var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
 string url = @"https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/ALY/59,14/forecast";
 _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "posterlagerkarte");
 var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
```